# Can I remove VirtFS folder after umounting?

Tags: centos, cpanel

I have removed all jailed shell permissions for all accounts.

I have unmounted all jailed folders using this command.

```
for i in `cat /proc/mounts | grep /home/virtfs | cut -d ' ' -f 2 ` ; do umount $i ; done
```

And with this command

```
/scripts/clear_orphaned_virtfs_mounts
```

Now, can I remove /home/virtfs, or should I let it be?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: virtfs mounts are recreated very quickly and because of bind mounts removing virtfs will cause /usr and /var to also be deleted rendering your server un-bootable.

You will not want to remove the virtfs folder as virtfs mounts are bind mounts to critical parts of your filesystem such as /usr, /var, etc.  Because virtfs mounts are created for a lot of things including email, php (with some configurations), cron, ssh, sftp, logins, and many others they can be recreated within milliseconds of removing them.

Because these are bind mounts, if you remove the virtfs with these mounts active you will most likely inevitably also remove the bind mount and that means if you delete virtfs you may also delete /var /usr /lib and other folders critical to your operating system.

Do not remove virtfs. I have seen at least 10 servers ruined by deleting virtfs.

Comment: i just deleted virtfs,my system is ruined. so what I need to do? recreate new server?